# Future Warning and User warning in KMeans Algo

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec

C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster_kmeans.py:1412: FutureWarning: The default value of `n_init` will change from 10 to 'auto' in 1.4. Set the value of `n_init` explicitly to suppress the warning
super()._check_params_vs_input(X, default_n_init=10)
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster_kmeans.py:1436: UserWarning: KMeans is known to have a memory leak on Windows with MKL, when there are less chunks than available threads. You can avoid it by setting the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS=1.
warnings.warn(

I used word2vec to form word embedding and then I used those for k-Means clusterning. then it showed this error on jupyter notebook. what should i do now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.